# Prove Alice Had Sent the Message Before

Tags: digital-signature

[image: Alice sends messages to Bob]

Alice just sent a message to Bob, but prior to that she had already sent the very same message. How can Bob prove that?

Comment: Do you mean that the 2 messages were sent at different ***times***? Because it is trivial to prove that Alice sent the message. What are the constraints? It would be trivial to use 3rd party proof. Do you want to prove it only using the factors represented in the diagram?  Is there a timestamp with the message?

Comment: @schroeder yes. Alice had sent the same message before this time, at an even earlier time. Bob needs to find evidence to convince people that. And I haven't got any more constraints about this problem.

Comment: Unless the sending time is somehow a part of the signature, you can't. You must rely on 3rd party proof (email logs, transmission logs, etc.)

Comment: You can show Alice's different signature value on each message.

Comment: If Alice sent the message through an email provider that signs messages with DKIM signatures (such as Gmail) then Bob can prove that Alice sent the message at the date and time that she sent it, by verifying the DKIM signature using the email provider's public DKIM key.

Comment: *"How can Bob prove that?"* - If it cannot be precluded that the `transmission` channel (or any mitm) duplicates messages, Bob cannot prove anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I see, I cannot find a 'perfect' solution. However, I have some ideas, which are listed below.

The first is the simple idea that we can use time as part of the signature. This can also be useful for preventing message replay attacks (MRA). If time does not match, then this signature will be seen as illegal.

The second also comes from normal methods for MRA prevention, that we may use some salt during communication. However, one of the shortcomings is that this method would require interaction between Alice and Bob.

And the last idea is not that widely used, however, still something old. Bob could keep a counter, and add the counter with the key for decryption (something like `hash(saved key+counter value)`). And every time he decrypts an encrypted message successfully, he increases the counter. This technique actually comes from some old idea of key generation I once read from a book (and after counter reaches a limit, go have a face-to-face talk (date) and refresh the key).

Comment: That last suggestion doesn't really work since anyone can just claim that Bob incremented it himself.

Comment: Well, actually Alice may still need to sign the encrypted message (which includes the counter, of course).  The signature can prove that no one else, including Bob, has modified it. And the signature protected content is encrypted with the counter, so we can prove that these are two different messages.